# Delete a single line from a file with a unix shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm working with a simple shell script that needs to delete a single line from a file if a string entered at command line is found. Instead it deletes the entire contents of the file.

the data file is like this(each entry is on a new line):

```
Name:Address:Phone:email
Joshua Brown:42404 Transport Center:380-(605)964-4223:jbrown0@desdev.cn
Margaret Elliott:24 Forest Plaza:48-(269)541-4040:melliott1@toplist.cz
Gary Flores:76868 Westport Drive:86-(478)534-8313:gflores2@reference.com
```

my code:

```
#assuming $1 is the pattern that needs to be searched for
#if found, delete the entire line
sed -i '/$1/d' filename
```

Comment: `sed -i "/$1/d" file` Good luck.

Comment: Try out [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net). It warns about this and other common issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed  -i 'Nd' filename
```

N means the line number , begin from 1